# $\int_{1}^\infty \sin^2(3x^\frac{7}{6})dx$ does in converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

$\int_{1}^\infty \sin^2(3x^\frac{7}{6})dx$ does in converge?

I think it diverges but i am not so sure about my solution so i will be glad for some remarks.
Using simple $\sin^2(x)$ identity i changed the integral to :
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^\infty1-\cos(6x^\frac{7}{6})dx$$
from here i believe we can already conclude that this integral diverges since $$\int_{1}^\infty1dx = \lim_{k\to \infty}
 x|_{1}^k = \infty -1 = \infty$$ so in total it diverges.

Comment: Write $y=x^{7/6}$.

Comment: $\int_1^{\infty} dx$ diverges, but $\int_1^{\infty} (1-\cos(6x^{7/6}))dx$ might still converge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

$$
\int_{1}^{\infty} \sin^2 (3x^{7/6}) dx
$$
set $y = 3x^{7/6}$ then $dy =  3\frac 76 x^{1/6} dx \Leftrightarrow dx = \frac 27 \frac{1}{x^{1/6}} = \frac 27 \frac{1}{y^{1/7}}$

we get

$$
\int_{1}^{\infty} \sin^2 (3x^{7/6}) dx = \frac 27\int_{3}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2(y)}{y^{1/7}} dy
$$

For $y>1$ we have that $\frac 1y \leq \frac {1}{y^{1/7}}$ so

$$
\frac 27\int_{3}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2(y)}{y^{1/7}} \geq
\frac 27 \int_{3}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2(y)}{y} dy
$$
We have that $\sin^2(y) \geq \frac 12$ whenever $\frac \pi 4 + n\pi \leq y \leq \ \frac {3\pi}{4} + n \pi, n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $I_n= \left[\frac \pi 4 + n\pi, \frac{3\pi}{4} + n \pi \right]$.

$$
\frac 27 \int_{3}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2(y)}{y} = 
\frac 27 \int_{[3,\infty)\cap \{y : sin^2 < \frac 12 \}} \frac{\sin^2(y)}{y} dy + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac 27 \int_{I_n} \frac{\sin^2(y)}{y}dy \geq \\
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac 27 \int_{I_n} \frac{1}{2y}dy = 
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac 2{14} \left( \log \left( \frac{\frac{\pi}{4} + n\pi}{ \frac{3\pi}{4} + n\pi} \right) \right) = \\
\frac 2{14} \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \log \left( 1 - \frac{2}{4n + 3} \right) > \infty
$$

Comment: For large $y$, we can only obtain $\frac{\sin^2(3y)}{y^{1/7}}\leq\frac{1}{y^{1/7}}$, but not the $\sim$ relation. So, something more is needed to show divergence of the integral.

Comment: @detnvvp wonder if OP read the details before accepting...

Comment: @detnvvp well we can say $$\lim_{x_\to\infty}  \frac{\sin^2(3y)}{y^\frac{1}{7}}\ * \frac{y^{1/7}}{1} = \sin^2(3y) $$ which by the convergence tests says that they are equals, hence the original diverges.

Comment: The limit of $\sin^2(3y)$ as $y\to\infty$ does not exist.

Comment: True, I tried another approach. @detnvvp

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_1^\infty \sin^2(3x^{\frac{7}{6}})dx$$
$u=3x^{7/6}$

$\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{7}{2}x^{1/6}$

$dx=\frac{2}{7}x^{-1/6}du$
$$I=\frac{2}{7}\int_3^\infty \frac{\sin^2(u)}{\sqrt[7]{u}}du$$
seeing as$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2(x)}{\sqrt{x}}dx$ is divergent it is most likely that this is also divergent